# Codemodel: how to implement method reference

Tags: java, java-8, sun-codemodel, jcodemodel

I have a interface having getter methods like below

```
public interface IAddress {
  AddressId getId();
  String getCity();
  String getCountry();
}
```

I want to create another class where I want to reference the getter methods of IAddress like `IAddress::getId` .

How can I achieve this in JCodeModel?

Comment: You don’t. Unless there will be a new version of that library supporting Java 8 features. The project page doesn’t look that promising…

Comment: @Holger Thanks for the info.. anyways could you suggest then how shall I refer an existing method by name.. i.e. `IAddress.getId()`

Comment: A method reference is just an idiom for creating an instance of a functional interface implementation calling the specified method. I’m sure that you can create that using the conventional way, i.e. creating a class implementing the interface and adding an implementation method that will invoke the target method, via codemodel.

Comment: You might check with this project for newer Java 8 features: https://github.com/phax/jcodemodel